# unable to send base64 image more than 100kb

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to send a base64 based data that is an png to PHP based script where i am unable to upload image more than 100kb below 100kb images are sending.

script is working fine on WAMP Server the problem is only on live server

here is that Javascript code which I am using to send data

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("image");
   ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
       
function uploadimg(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var image = canvas.toDataURL();
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('picture', image);
    request.open('POST', 'upload.php');
    request.onload = function () {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            console.log('all done: ');
            
        } else {
            console.log('Nope');
        }
    };
    request.send(fd);
}
```

here is upload.php code

```
 define('IMAGE_DIR', 'image/');
 $img = $_POST['picture'];
 $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
 $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
 $data = base64_decode($img);
 $file = IMAGE_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
 $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

Comment: What is the value of attribute `post_max_size` in the `php.ini` on your live server?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2184541/11430357

Comment: What is your console output when you upload image over 100kb ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Comment: @shujat132 getting 500 internal error over 100kb

Comment: @Evgeniy `post_max_size` is 512MB and upload_max_filesize = 512MB

Comment: If you getting `500` code you need to look at the `apache` error logs. The error is references to `PHP`

Comment: @asimdev can you write die('test'); before define('IMAGE_DIR', 'image/'); and try to submit form and please past here console out put again

Comment: @shujat132 getting same 500 internal error

Comment: @asimdev Its mean there is no problem with uploading of image of over 100kb, rather some there is some error on your php  code.

Comment: @shujat132 i pasted php code what i have in this question. one more thing is it is working fine in localhost wamp server it is not working on live